# Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $\sup_{x \in \Bbb R}|f'(x)| \lt \infty$. Then

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-continuity, cauchy-sequences

(UGC CSIR-2015, DECEMEMBER, MATHEMATICAL SCIENCES)

> 1. $f$ maps a bounded sequence to a bounded sequence.
> 2. $f$ maps a Cauchy sequence to a Cauchy sequence.
> 3. $f$ maps a convergent sequence to a convergent sequence.
> 4. $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I choose all of the options as possible answers because the condition $\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|f'(x)| \lt \infty$ forces $f$ to be uniformly continuous.(Because $f$ becomes Lipschitz and Lipschitz condition implies uniform continuity)

i.e. $\frac {|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \le \sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|f'(x)|$
$ \forall x,y$.

Hence all other options are bound to be true.

Am I correct?

Comment: correct. The condition even implies that $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: $user295959 Exactly!! I forgot to put this above in the post.

Comment: I had asked this question on 21st December 2015 while @S.Panja-1729 had asked this question on 22nd December 2015. Then why is it so that my question is duplicate of his?

Comment: Which question was asked first is not the prime concern. If the newer question is better in itself or has received better answers, that's a reason to close the older as a duplicate of the newer. Here, I reversed the direction of the duplicate because the answer here is more comprehensive, the answer at the other question treats only the first point.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer and I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All are correct.

1. If $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb R$ is bounded, i.e., $\lvert x_n\rvert\le M<\infty$, then
   $$
   \lvert\,f(x_n)-f(x_1)\rvert=\lvert x_n-x_1\rvert\lvert f'(y_n)\rvert,
   $$
   for some $y_n\in(x_1,x_n)$, by virtue of the Mean Value Theorem, and hence
   $$
   \lvert\,f(x_n)\rvert\le \lvert\,f(x_1)\rvert +\lvert x_n-x_1\rvert\lvert f'(y_n)\rvert\le \lvert\,f(x_1)\rvert +2M \|f'\|_\infty.
   $$
2. If If $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb R$ is Cauchy,
   then
   $$
   \lvert\,f(x_m)-f(x_n)\rvert=\lvert\,f'(y_{m,n})\rvert\lvert x_m-x_n\rvert\le\|f'\|_\infty \lvert x_m-x_n\rvert,
   $$
   hence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ Cauchy.
3. If $x_n\to x$, then 
   $$
   \lvert\,f(x_n)-f(x)\rvert=\lvert\,f'(y_n)\rvert\lvert x_n-x\rvert\le\|f'\|_\infty \lvert x_n-x\rvert,
   $$
   where $y\in(x,x_n)$, and hence $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.
4. If $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then 
   $$
   \lvert\,f(x)-f(y)\rvert\le\|f'\|_\infty \lvert x-y\rvert,
   $$
   etc...